# Avoid column from rowcallback datatable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

I have a table and in this table there's a column with buttons, every button has a functionality accord to the row data, this buttons are built in PHP, I want to add a new functionality with rowcallback but when I click one of those buttons the "rowcallback" trigger is also "executed"

How can I prevent a column from being inside of the rowcallback?

Comment: Can you exactly explain, what do you mean about "rowcallback"?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show us the relevant (and formatted) DataTables code, with some sample data. It _sounds_ as if you may need to use a [column renderer](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) - but without seeing any code, that is just a complete guess. And we also need to see how you are handling your button click events.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to take the [tour] and read [ask] for more guidelines on improving your question. For example, have you researched this problem? If so, what did you find?